# How to use .setTimeZone for a class member?

Tags: java, android

Experts,
I would like to get current datetime in a given timezone for global usage.

So,
I create a class like below, but it shows syntax error for the df.setTimeZone statement. What is the neat way to achieve this? More specific, I would like to set timezone property for a class member rather than a local variable.

I defined many date format through SimpleDateFormat, how to specify a timezone for all of them? (.setTimeZone seems only for one date format) Thanks.

```
public class Global {

static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GIVEN_TIMEZONE"));

static String strDate = df.format(new Date());

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely *must* do it with `static` fields, you need the code to be in a `static` initializer block:

```
class Global {

    static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    static {
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GIVEN_TIMEZONE"));
    }
    static String strDate = df.format(new Date());

}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you have lot of dates to do like that, with different date formats and/or time zones, it may be better to use a helper method.

```
class Global {

    static String strDate = format(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy", "GIVEN_TIMEZONE");

    private static String format(Date date, String format, String timeZoneID) {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneID));
        return df.format(date);
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks good. Thanks a lot! But I have so many SimpleDateFormat, need to set timezone for them one by one?

Comment: well, not so many, about 12 formats, I just thought if can set them all would be more grace...

Answer (score 0):

Please try in below possible syntax:

```
String dtc = "2014-04-02T07:59:02.111Z";
SimpleDateFormat readDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
readDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // Important line
Date date = readDate.parse(dtc);

SimpleDateFormat writeDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH.mm");
writeDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+04:00"));  // Important line
String s = writeDate.format(date);
```

You need to import below class:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html